# Django: Unable to import models globally

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-shell

I am running some python scripts which pertains with a django application.
So I manually made a folder (named scripts) that contains some python scripts but is not made using `./manage.py startapp scripts`. Along with this folder there is a `modelsapp` django app (which contains my models) and then `project` folder containing `settings.py` and `urls.py`.

I run `./manage.py shell < scripts/script.py` to run my script.

Now here is a sample code of my scripts.py

```
from modelsapp.models import *
print(Room.objects.all())
```

This works pretty well. Now consider a second case. I now just run `./manage.py shell` and then put the following commands-

```
>>>from modelsapp.models import *
>>>def init():
...    print(Room.objects.all())
...
>>>init()
```

This also works pretty well. But now when I run the above code through the file in the first case, it says `NameError: name 'Room' is not defined`

It looks like the model classes which I just imported aren't accessibly inside a function.
This behavior is a bit weird.

Please help. In case I missed anything to mention, do comment below.

Edit: Since this is a bit weird behavior and am not able to find any answers to it, I am just going to pass the class `Room` directly to the function `init()` as a parameter to get the work done as of now.

Comment: what about `from project.modelsapp.models import *` or `from modelsapp.models import Room`?

Comment: First one gives the Import error

Comment: Second one it says the same thing.

Comment: `NameError: name 'Room' is not defined`

Comment: I have this. `modelsapp.apps.ModelsappConfig`

Answer (score 0):

after you run the django shell, you can run your script with:

```
>>>execfile('filename.py')
```

if you want to run it in a normal python shell (not using python manage.py shell) you have to do:

```
import django
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project(name.settings")
django.setup()
```

Comment: Yup, this is how it works, but still the question is, why isn't it working with my method.

Comment: how do you run your file exactly?

Comment: I've mentioned it in the second paragraph of the description.